# Apply a filter to a Supabase stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

I'm looking to apply a filter to a stream from Supabase but can't find any example of how to achieve this. Here is my function (without a filter):

```
Stream<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _getProducts() {
   final response = supabase.from('products').stream().execute();
   return response;
}
```

I would like to apply a simple 'eq' filter to the stream. This is how it would look as a future:

```
Future<PostgrestResponse> _getProducts() async {
   final user = supabase.auth.currentUser;
   final response =
       await supabase.from('products').select().eq('uuid', user!.id).execute();
   return response;
 }
```

Unfortunately applying the same 'select().eq()' logic doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you.

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _getProducts() async {    
final user = supabase.auth.currentUser;    
final response = await 
supabase.from('products:uuid=eq.${user!.id}').stream(['uuid']).execute();   
return response;  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how can i compare Strings?

Comment: Inside stream(), you need to add primaryKey: ["column_name"]...